# SignalR responses overwriting headers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, owin

I've built a simple SignalR hub that lives within a WebAPI service, I've included all the required CORS attributes on both WebAPI and SignalR. My WebAPI endpoints are all working as expected but SignalR isn't.

I've tried all I can think of and all I can find online but nothing works, I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666185/1422608), and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084430/1422608) to no solution.

My SignalR extension method looks like this

```
public static IAppBuilder UseSignalrNotificationService(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HubConfiguration();
        config.Resolver = new HubDependencyResolver();
        config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR(config);

        return app;
    }
```

And I even tried adding the response headers on all requests using the Web.config but I allways get the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MyApplicationServer/notifications/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&access_token=&connectionData=. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'MyOriginService' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After more research and fiddling with the server side of the problem, I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513360/1422608) and found the error to be with the client side of the request. according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/a5fb42a757f0767fc153cbc549ed87a14d68cc66), the "withCredentials" parameter of the request is always set to 'true'. The solution was to call on the client the start method as follows:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ withCredentials: false }).done(function () {  //... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the request somewhere with some kind of global interceptor? For some reason, the XMLHttpRequest starts with `withCredentials:true` and this is forbidden when the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to *.

What about setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to 'http://MyApplicationServer'? It's safer than * and will remove your problem at source.

Comment: I tried changing the CORS policy of SignalR to specify the origins to no result, something weird's happening with the request and its headers

Comment: @evilpilaf did you ever work out how to specify origins? I can't get it to work.